# Help optimizing integer math

Tags: c#, math, optimization

I need some help optimizing a section of math heavy code. I've done the profiling, and isolated the slow method. The problem is that the lines individually aren't slow, but they're called many many many times, so I need to really pinch microseconds here.

This code is used to convert pixel data after performing an NTSC filtering. I've provided the profiling data next to the lines as a % of total running time, so you can see what needs work. This function overall accounts for about half of my running time (48% self, 53% with children).

```
// byte[] ntscOutput;
// ushort[] filtered; - the pixels are ushort, because of the texture color depth

int f_i = 0;
int row = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 269440; i++)                                  // 3.77 %
{
    int joined = (ntscOutput[f_i + 1] << 8) + ntscOutput[f_i];    // 6.6 %
    f_i += 2;                                                     // 1.88 %

    filtered[i] = (ushort)joined;                                 // 2.8 %

    ushort red = (ushort)(joined & 0xf800);                       // }
    ushort green = (ushort)(joined & 0x7e0);                      //  > 2.36 % each
    ushort blue = (ushort)(joined & 0x1f);                        // }

    red = (ushort)((red - (red >> 3)) & 0xf800);                  // }
    green = (ushort)((green - (green >> 3)) & 0x7e0);             //  > 4.24 % each
    blue = (ushort)((blue - (blue >> 3)) & 0x1f);                 // }

    filtered[i + 602] = (ushort)(red | green | blue);             // 5.65 %

    row++;
    if (row > 601)
    {
        row = 0;
        i += 602;
    }
}
```

I'm open to any method of optimizing. If it's not really possible to improve the actual math operations, maybe something with unsafe code and pointers would work in manipulating the arrays, to prevent so many casts? Maybe changing my array types somehow, or maybe some kind of loop unrolling? I'm confident that it's possible, because the filtering operation itself is a huge C library function with tons of loops and math, and the whole thing totals 1.35% of my running time.

Comment: Just in case the casts _do_ play a significant role, maybe you could make `joined` a `ushort`? Even if it turns out it doesn't have any positive impact on performance, it should at least make your code less cast-ey.

Comment: @zneak I would, but every math operation returns an int again, so I still need all those casts. It really annoys me, so I hope the casts have no cost to them.

Comment: Huh, I thought they returned the largest type used, but you're right. In that case, maybe you could use `int`s everywhere until you need to cast for `filtered`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm wondering, since you're looping 269440 times (well, less with the row variable), and there are only 2^16 possibilities to the filtered variable result, have you considered a **look-up table**? I'm not sure how well a 2^16 long array would sit in C#, but it might be worth a try.

Comment: Please, do give us your timing on this :)

Comment: @BenVoigt: Is there a way to see the actual edit times, not just X hours ago (until it gets old enough that it shows the time stamp, that is)?

Comment: @MPelletier: Yeah, move your mouse over the "hours ago", you'll get a tooltip.  At least in Chrome you do.  That's how I know the answers were posted 30 minutes apart, even though the page just shows "7 hours ago" and "8 hours ago".  (Note, it's actually 30+/-5 minutes because of the possibility of ninja-editing)

Comment: @BenVoigt: OK, my initial entry was just about a look-up table, at 04:28, and Marino's edit #4 adding his look-up table solution was at 04:44, if I'm reading it right.

Comment: I added the precalculated part later. If that is the real solution and MPelletier suggested practically the same thing (lookuptable) then credit is due to him, and I'm giving him a bonus +1, however we should not whine about who has been accepter because really we are here to help not to collect points :)

Comment: @Marino: Agreed. I just didn't want a claim of illegitimate acceptance hanging above my head, that's only why I brought up the times. Answer acceptance is the responsibility of the asker, after all. +1 to you as well :)

Comment: @MPelletier @Marino Yeah I did look at edit times to see who should get the accept credit. And I gave my +1 to both.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that.  I did look at the answer times, but I missed part of the edit history.  Again, sorry.

Answer (score 5):

You are asking for micro optimizations, but have you tried macro optimizations first?

269440 is divisible by any 2^n, that means you can easily thread this code to the number of processors you have, and have basically the speed n-tupled.

Just be sure to not declare threads inside this code though.

Micro optimization using the [unchecked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) keyword could probably be achieved in the rgb block, by surrounding everything with unchecked {}, but that probably won't aid much.

The real optimization would be:

For all possible values of `joined` (ushort) store all resulting values of `filtered[i + 602]` into an array with the index of each being (ushort)joined, and do not use calculation but get the value directly from the array.

Then skip the rgb part and use as the loop body:

```
filtered[i] = (ushort)joined;
filtered[i+602] = precalculatedValues[(ushort)joined];
```

You could that way convert joined to ushort (after removing the bitwise operations).

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to split the ushort joined and put the result back together.
You can compute the output directly using

```
 filtered[i + 602] = (ushort)(joined - ((joined >> 3) & 0x18e3));
```

Let me explain this:
In your example blue uses bits 0-4, green uses 5-10 and red uses 11-15. The bits of joined are (in big endian order)

> rrrr rggg gggb bbbb

joined >> 3 shifts all components (red, gree, blue) by 3. I.e joined >> 3 has the format

> 000r rrrr gggg ggbb

We want to mask of the bits from one component that spill into another component. This is done
using 0x18e3. I.e. (joined >> 3) & 0x18e3 has the format

> 000r r000 ggg0 00bb

Next you do the subtraction of

```
joined - ((joined >> 3) & 0x18e3)
```

This does subtract the shifted rgb components from the original in one step. However, you have to consider underflows. I.e. you don't want that an underflow in the green component is propagated into the red component. A little thought shows that this is not a problem. All the shifted components are smaller than their original value, and hence there can be no underflows. In other words, the single statement above should just work fine. (Of course, you will still have to test carefully).

For more speed one would do this operation on multiple pixels in parallel. I.e. if you had 4 pixels packed in a uint64 then it would be just as easy to do this operation on all 4 pixels at once. (But I'm not sure whether type-casting ushort arrays to uint64 arrays is easily possible).

Comment: This is exactly what I was going to say. He can also put the pixels in a struct that overlays an array of bytes and an array of shorts so explicit concatenation is not needed. Or union with an array of a larger type for increased parallelism as you suggest. It's SIMD is plain old C.

Answer (score 2):

You can do red and blue together, since the empty space for green in the middle will prevent interaction:

```
ushort redblue = (ushort)(joined & 0xf81f);
ushort green = (ushort)(joined & 0x7e0);

redblue = (ushort)((redblue - (redblue >> 3)) & 0xf81f);
green = (ushort)((green - (green >> 3)) & 0x7e0);

filtered[i + 602] = (ushort)(redblue | green);
```

To improve readability you should define constants for all those magic numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I followed some tricks on this page:
http://developer.amd.com/documentation/articles/pages/7162004127.aspx

Maybe someone else wil find some extra points of that page? Welcome to comment below.

```
uint f_i = 0;
uint row = 0;
ushort red, green, blue;
ushort joined;
for (uint i = 0; i < 269440; i++)                                  // 3.77 %
{
    joined = (ntscOutput[f_i + 1] << 8) + ntscOutput[f_i];    // 6.6 %
    f_i += 2;                                                     // 1.88 %

    filtered[i] = joined;                                 // 2.8 %

    red = (joined & 0xf800);                       // }
    green = (joined & 0x7e0);                      //  > 2.36 % each
    blue = (joined & 0x1f);                        // }

    red = (ushort)((red - (red >> 3)) & 0xf800);                  // }
    green = (ushort)((green - (green >> 3)) & 0x7e0);             //  > 4.24 % each
    blue = (ushort)((blue - (blue >> 3)) & 0x1f);                 // }

    filtered[i + 602] = (ushort)(red | green | blue);             // 5.65 %

    row++;
    if (row > 601)
    {
        row = 0;
        i += 602;
    }
}
```

Comment: He's working in C#. And um, aside from the casts, what did you take off?

Comment: While he may be working in C#, there is nothing about this code that restricts it to such. This code would work fine in C and C++

Comment: Yes, but your solution has to work in C#; and the casts that you removed are mandatory in C# (or else you get `error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type `int' to `short'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`).

Comment: Moving instantiation of red, green, and blue variables outside the loop is a nice touch. In theory this is optimized (I think) by most compilers, but in practice, better to instantiate once outside.

Comment: The filters to red (0xf800), green (0x7e0), and blue (0x1f) could also be declared as ushort constants once, less casting that way.

Comment: @MPelletier, all bit operations in C# on types smaller than `int` return an `int`, so there's no getting away from the casts.

Comment: @zneak. Drats. OK then, red, green and blue should be ints, and filtered only can be ushort.

Answer (score 0):

(This should stack with the other answers, such as use of a lookup table)

Yes, you can achieve a considerable speedup using unsafe.  There's no reason for the line setting `joined` to take 6%, and the loop condition can also be improved.  Try:

```
int row = 0;
int remaining = 269440/2;
fixed (ushort* p = (ushort*)&ntscOutput[0])
    do {
        int joined = *p;
        p++;

        // ...

    } while (--remaining > 0);
```